# Long table without page breaks

Tags: tables, longtable

I'm looking to create a long table of results to be shown on a computer and therefore, I'd like to change the normal a4 or US letter (which is too small) for a document whose size changes with the content. Is there such a thing easily implementable?

Comment: Is there *any* bound on how tall a page can be?

Comment: @Mico -- i think \maxdimen` would apply there.  (but i haven't tried it or dug into the documentation.)

Comment: @Mico you can put more than `\maxdimen` material in a box but you can't specify `\pdfpageheight` more than `\maxdimen` so you can sort of typeset more than that but it will be clipped in the final pdf and you won't see it.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi&\roman{enumi}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```